# Macro Template and Expansion

Tags: c, gcc, macros

> Consider the following program.

> **Practice.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define P(x,y,z) (x+y+z) 

main()
{
  int x,y,z,i,j,k;

  printf("\n  Number I = ");
  scanf("%d",&i);
  printf("\n Number II = ");
  scanf("%d",&j);
  printf("\nNumber III = ");
  scanf("%d",&k);

  printf("\n    Result = %d\n",P(i,j,k));
}
```

Now if I run `gcc -E Practice.c` than the output will be

```
# 2 "Practice.c" 2


main()
{
  int x,y,z,i,j,k;

  printf("\n  Number I = ");
  scanf("%d",&i);
  printf("\n Number II = ");
  scanf("%d",&j);
  printf("\nNumber III = ");
  scanf("%d",&k);

  printf("\n    Result = %d\n",(i+j+k));
}
```

> In here, the **macro** `P(i,j,k)` is replaced by `(i+j+k)` and it is clearly visible on the command screen.

My question is, what exactly happens to `#include <stdio.h>` in here ?

Does it also gets replaced by the files of `stdio`, the same way as `#define P(x,y,z) (x+y+z)` or it is just a way to link the contents of `stdio` to the `main()`.

And, what is `# 2 "Practice.c" 2` in the output after using `gcc -E Practice.c` ?

Comment: Try scrolling your terminal window back a little. All that stuff came from `stdio.h`.

Comment: The `# 2` line is telling the compiler what source file and line the following code came from, so that it can generate error messages that have that information in it.

Answer (score 1):

During preprocessing, an #include directive is actually replaced by the content of included file. Moreover this included file itself is preprocessed, so if it contains any other include directive, another file is included etc.

Very usualy, the preprocessor and compiler are two different programs and the output of preprocessing is sent to compiler by a pipe. Compiler itself does not open and read source files.

In this context it is clear that there must be a mechanism how preprocessor can tell the compiler the origin of code. This is necessary for error messages. If there is a syntax error, it is not detected by preprocessor, it is found by compiler and the compiler needs to display the exact line  and source file where the error is. However, when reading only one stream from pipe, it is impossible to get this information without an additional form. This is why the lines like

```
 # 2 "Practice.c" 2
```

appears. It is information about actual origin of source code. In this case, the preprocessor informs that the code following this line is coming from the file "Practice.c" and the next line is the second line of this source code. Compiler can then increase line numbers for next sequence of lines until the next such directive (often called and used as #line directive).

Answer (score 0):

The preprocessor directive `#define` is for macro expansion. The directive `#include` is for header file inclusion. So `#include <stdio.h>` puts the contents of the standard header file to the current file. You can compare the source file and the preprocessed file to see what came from the header `stdio.h`.

Comment: `int __attribute__((__cdecl__)) __attribute__ ((__nothrow__)) _getw (FILE*);`
This is just 1 line of those few hundred lines appearing on my screen.
You mean all those lines are the result of `#include <stdio.h>`.

Comment: @VSP yes. it has to be.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly a header file is simply a text file which has prototypes(declaration of functions) and many other things. **(IMP: Headers files only have declarations not definitions).**

In simple words `#include<stdio.h>` means to insert/include everything from `stdio.h` file into your source code file. here `< >` indicates the `stdio.h`file is present in a special folder which is known to compiler.(which will have  many other header files)

If you write `#include"stdio.h"` this means to insert/include everything from `stdio.h` file into your source code file. But here `" "` indicates that the `stdio.h` file is present in the current folder where your practice.c is present.(as its not,it will give error msg if you write like this)

Lets understand the above concept with some **"not so practical"** Program,Assume I have created a file called `myheader.h` which has some text like this.

**myheader.h**

```
Hello am nothing untill am something......
```

Now I write a program in practice.c (present in same folder where myheader.h file is present).

```
#include"myheader"
int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

Now if I compile(or i should just exactly say PreProcess) above code using command **gcc -E practice.c**

The output will be

```
Hello am nothing untill am something......
int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

This inserting contents of a header file into source file is called **File Inclusion.** (which is different from **Macro Substitution**)

Macro substitution means to substitute something in place of a thing(which you did with `#define P(x,y,z) (x+y+z)` ). If a Same Macro is used in many programs what you can do is, you can write those Macros in a separate header file and include it in your source files.Like that you can **Re-Use** macros without writing them **again and again** in source files.

At last if you want to correctly see the Preprocessed output, use this command **gcc -E practice.c -o abc.txt** This saves all the output of the **pre-processing** stage into separate file named abc.txt file. once you open the **abc.txt** file you will find many lines of code(more than hundred) inserted from the `stdio.h` header file into abc.txt,
You will find many prototypes(declarations) of commonly used like function's like `printf()`,`scanf()` and much more than that(**Macros** and other stuff) inserted, and your code(which you wrote) will be sitting in the end of file.you have to scroll down to the end to see your code.